# How to make Log4Net work with ASP.NET Core 3.1 using Dependency Injection?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependencies, log4net, code-injection

I am trying to use log4Net in an ASP.NET Core 3.1 application and I am trying to get it to work with Dependency Injection using controllers. I am successfully able to use Log4Net using `LogManager.GetLogger(type)`. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a sample of the code I am using for logging now:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private static readonly log4net.ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Logger));

    public HomeController()
    {
        _log.Debug("Test");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any services you want to inject into a Controller must be registered in `Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection)` (Startup.cs), or in `Program.CreateHostBuilder(string [])` (Program.cs) usually after `CreateDefaultBuilder` and `ConfigurWebHostDefaults`.

You can register the service using the following:

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => /* ... */)
        .ConfigureLogging(builder =>
        {   // Configuration here:
            builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
            builder.AddLog4Net("log4net.config");
        });
```

Then, you can inject using the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<T>` (where `T` is the class being logged), which will use Log4Net:

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller {
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _log;

    // A suitable logger instance is created by the runtime DI:
    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> log)
    {
        _log = log;
        _log.Debug("Test");
    }
}
```

For more information, [here is a tutorial](https://www.thecodebuzz.com/log4net-file-logging-console-logging-asp-net-core/).

Comment: Thank you very much. I know I am late but this really helped alot.